# MySQL - Calculating a value from two columns in each row, using the result in a WHERE or HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, division

I have a MySQL db schema like so:

```
id    flags     views    done
-------------------------------
1     2         20       0
2     66        100      0
3     25        40       0
4     30        60       0 

... thousands of rows ...
```

I want to update all of the rows whose flags / views are >= 0.2. First as a test I want to try to SELECT to see how many rows would actually get updated. I tried:

```
SELECT flags/views AS poncho FROM mytable HAVING poncho > 0.2
```

But this only returns like 2 rows and I *know* there should be a lot more than that. It seems like it's calculating the poncho value on all rows or something odd. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You know there should be, but the database says there are 2. Have you considered where flags or views isnull => flags/views = null => not in your result set.

Comment: Ah yeah, apparently another query was shutting down any more possible flags so I think the result is there are far less matches than I expected - oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `WHERE` clause instead of `HAVING`:

```
SELECT flags/views AS poncho FROM mytable WHERE flags/views > 0.2
```

`HAVING` aggregates all identical values into one row. The SQL standard would not allow a `HAVING` clause without a corresponding `GROUP BY`, but MySQL is very permissive with the standard. What you have there is effectively the same as

```
SELECT flags/views AS poncho
FROM   mytable
GROUP  BY poncho
HAVING poncho > 0.2
```

More in the manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html).